# Kivy: How to change x axis ticks from numbers to date or time values in kivy garden graph?

Tags: python, graph, kivy, python-3.8

I want to change the x-axis of `kivy garden Graph` from **numbers** to **date values**.

I want something like this:

[image]

### Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy_garden.graph import Graph, LinePlot
import math


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.plot = LinePlot(line_width=1.5, color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
        self.graph = Graph(xlabel='Date', ylabel='Y', x_ticks_minor=5,
                           x_ticks_major=25, y_ticks_major=1,
                           y_grid_label=True, x_grid_label=True, padding=5,
                           x_grid=True, y_grid=True, xmin=0, xmax=200, ymin=-2, ymax=2,
                           x_ticks_angle=90)
        self.plot.points = [(x, math.sin(x / 10.)) for x in range(0, 201)]
        self.graph.add_plot(self.plot)
        self.add_widget(self.graph)


class MyKivy(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyKivy().run()
```

Any Solution? Thank you in advance...